# Rank subset of MySQL results

Tags: mysql

I have several hundred thousand products in a MySQL database. Each product is mapped to one subcategory, each subcategory is mapped to one category, and each category is mapped to one department.

I need to calculate the sales rank of a given product within its subcategory/category/department respectively, and also fetch two products ranked directly above it and two products ranked directly below it. Here is an SQL Fiddle to fetch the rank of ALL products in the subcategory:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4aad/6

How can I refactor the query to return only the product with a given product_id plus two rows above and below? For instance, for product_id 8 I would want to return only these rows:

```
╔══════╦════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║ RANK ║  DESCRIPTION   ║ TOTAL_SALES ║ PRODUCT_ID ║
╠══════╬════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║    2 ║ Digital SLR 2  ║        8000 ║          2 ║
║    3 ║ Digital SLR 7  ║        5998 ║          7 ║
║    4 ║ Digital SLR 8  ║        5997 ║          8 ║
║    5 ║ Digital SLR 1  ║        3297 ║          1 ║
║    6 ║ Digital SLR 4  ║        3200 ║          4 ║
╚══════╩════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

For product_id 3, the data returned would be as follows:

```
╔══════╦════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║ RANK ║  DESCRIPTION   ║ TOTAL_SALES ║ PRODUCT_ID ║
╠══════╬════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║    6 ║ Digital SLR 4  ║        3200 ║          4 ║
║    7 ║ Digital SLR 6  ║        2599 ║          6 ║
║    8 ║ Digital SLR 3  ║        2468 ║          3 ║
║    9 ║ Digital SLR 10 ║        1000 ║         10 ║
║   10 ║ Digital SLR 5  ║        1000 ║          5 ║
╚══════╩════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

So the product_id is known to the query, but rank is unknown until the query is executed.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Done. I've almost completely rewritten the question as well, in an attempt to make it easier to understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method for doing this that just uses MySQL variables -- so you don't have to calculate the rank twice.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             @therank := if(product_id = 8, rank, @therank) as therank
      from (SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 AS rank,
                   description, total_sales, product_id
            FROM (SELECT ol.product_id, p.description,
                         sum(ol.item_sell_price) AS total_sales
                  FROM products p INNER JOIN
                       order_lines ol
                       ON p.id = ol.product_id
                  WHERE p.subcategory_id = 1
                  GROUP BY ol.product_id
                  ORDER BY total_sales DESC
                 ) t1 cross join
                 (SELECT @rn := 0) const
           ) t cross join
           (select @therank := 0) const
     ) t
where @therank between rank - 2 and rank + 2
order by rank
```

The inner subquery, using `@rn` calculates the rank.  The next level goes through the data and sets `@therank` to the rank for the given product.  Finally, this is used as a `between` statement at the outer most level.

MySQL does materialize subqueries.  In this case, that probably performs much better than recalculating the rank.

Comment: +1 Gordon to the rescue. I was just checking back to see if anyone had done the hard yards, otherwise I was going to answer it, but you've saved me the work :)

Answer (score 0):

A query like:

```
SELECT rank, description, total_sales
FROM ( ... your query ... )
ORDER BY rank
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 3
```

will give you records from 3 to 7.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response! :-) My problem is that I need to calculate the value to use in the LIMIT or OFFSET clause as part of the query, it would be based on the value of "rank" for a particular product_id.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it that you need to dynamically choose the range to display :(

Comment: Sorry I wasn't too clear, I included quite a bit of unnecessary information. Rewritten the question now.